# Android Images Folder in a ImageView

Tags: java, android

Sorry in advance for my english.

I want to import images folder of my smartphone. I want used these images to do a gallery.
My problem is when I put the images in an array, after I can't put each images of the array in a ImageView.

It's my code for using the gallery

```
public class SeeGallery extends Activity {

File[] listFile ;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_see_gallery);

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/ProjectKozaImages");
    listFile = folder.listFiles();

    // Note that Gallery view is deprecated in Android 4.1---
    Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery1);
    gallery.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id)
    {
        // display the images selected
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
        imageView.setImageResource(listFile[position]);
        }
        });
    }

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private int itemBackground;
    public ImageAdapter(Context c)
    {
    context = c;
    // sets a grey background; wraps around the images
    TypedArray a =obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.MyGallery);
    itemBackground = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.MyGallery_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
    a.recycle();
    }
    // returns the number of images
    public int getCount() {
    return listFile.length;
    }
    // returns the ID of an item
    public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
    }
    // returns the ID of an item
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
    }
    // returns an ImageView view
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setImageResource(listFile[position]);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(100, 100));
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(itemBackground);
    return imageView;
    }
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert the filePath stored in your FileArray to a Bitmap first...

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(listFile[position].getAbsolutePath());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```